# What is the best tool for adding user generated JavaScript to a C# application?

Tags: c#, javascript, scripting

I have looked into JInt, IronJS, and Windows Script Host and can not see which would be better to use for calling user generated JavaScripts which call in an API I will be creating.

JInt seems to be the winner at present due to it also offerring debugging abilities, however WSH seems plausible. I just can't see how it would work even having read many tutorials on how it is implemented.

Lastly JInt claims the CodeDomProvider technique leads to memory leaks, apart from this reference I haven't found anything else to back this up. Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: Check out [Jurassic](http://jurassic.codeplex.com/) too.

Comment: Thanks for that link. I am now looking at Jurassic and a few others to see which performs the best. If they fail to perform at the level of a browser at least, I will look into node.js and how I can send it messages to run scripts for me.

Answer (score 1):

There is a project which is called [Script#](http://projects.nikhilk.net/ScriptSharp). Have a look and see if that's what you wanted.